# Not able to increment month by 1 in java

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have to store dates of next 30 days in mysql db starting from current date. If the month reaches its end it should automatically start taking dates from nxt month . This is happening properly when I am storing date in the format like 
"Mon Jul 11 13:28:23 IST 2016" . It is happening like this.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
if(repetitionSpan.equals("weekly")){
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++){               
            String insertQuery="insert into notifications(notificationId,messageForUser,notificationReceiver,notificationSender,status,timeOfNotification,typeOfNotification)values('"+"RM"+calendar.getTimeInMillis()+"','"+notificationDetails.getMessageForUser()+"','"+notificationDetails.getNotificationReceiver()+"','"+notificationDetails.getNotificationSender()+"','"+notificationDetails.getStatus()+"','"+calendar.getTime()+"','"+notificationDetails.getTypeOfNotification()+"')";
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(insertQuery).executeUpdate(); 
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
```

In the ablove case it is working fine. But in another case where I am storing date in the format "yyyy/mm/dd" it is not working.

```
String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy/mm/dd";
String date_string = "2001/08/12";
java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf =
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
Date date = (Date)sdf.parse(date_string);
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.setTime(date); 
int maxDay = c1.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
System.out.println("maxDay is"+maxDay);
System.out.println("last month date is"+c1.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println("Date is : " + sdf.format(c1.getTime()));
for(int i=0;i<maxDay;i++){
    c1.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    System.out.println("Date + 1 month is : " + sdf.format(c1.getTime()));
}
```

Output is:- Month is not getting incremented (even after date has reached 31)

Comment: Could you clarify what 'not working' means exactly?

Comment: `String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy/mm/dd";` - That's Year/Minutes/Day

Comment: @Rhayene I have updated my question which answers your query

Comment: Erm, no - _dude_. You may **think** it is obvious but that doesn't make it right. Check JavaDocs.

Comment: @JavaDevelopers please, take a look into [`API`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or my answer....  `mm` is minute.... `:S`

Comment: @JordiCastilla oops.. my mistake .. It thought it is month :p I have changes it to yyyy/MM/dd. Bt still its not getting incremented

Comment: @JavaDevelopers Just check your sources if someone is hinting an error to you. I didn't but some ppl take such a reply as you gave it pretty personal and feel offended. Java offers some "pitfalls" where you are diluted by an "obvious" method name. I just say "available" ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in the format.

```
String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy/mm/dd";
```

`mm` means

> Minute in hour

So, in order to get correct `Date` you must use:

```
String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd";
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
maxDay is31
last month date is31
Date is : 2001/08/12
Date + 1 month is : 2001/08/13
Date + 1 month is : 2001/08/14
Date + 1 month is : 2001/08/15
Date + 1 month is : 2001/08/16
Date + 1 month is : 2001/08/17
Date + 1 month is : 2001/08/18
Date + 1 month is : 2001/08/19
.....
Date + 1 month is : 2001/09/11
Date + 1 month is : 2001/09/12
```

---

[**WORKING IDEONE DEMO!**](https://ideone.com/Mgwd7L)

Comment: In the above method of mine in which I am storing date in different format I am not incrementing month ,it is happening itself when it reaches month end . Can't this happen in this solution of yours too?

Comment: @JavaDevelopers what? I dont understand what you mean, can you please provide an example please? I will adapt my answer `:)`

Comment: @JavaDevelopers in this answer, Jordi is incrementing one day at a time.

Comment: @JavaDevelopers, I've checked your [questions tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6433626/java-developers?tab=questions) and I've seen you've not accepted any one. You must know that if this or any answer has solved your question please consider **[accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark**. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and **gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself**. Of course there is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @JordiCastilla Sorry new to stackoverflow and did'nt knew this and I tried to like your answer by clicking on like button but it needs enough reputation. But now i have accepted your answer and from now onwards I will do this always. Thanx agin.!!!!

Comment: don't worry, we're here to help. You can do it also in past questions if some answer solved the problems, this is the way sackoverflow works to tell others this is a resolved problem `:)`